# I want to make a sidebar like google play store by css and js

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make a sidebar like gool
e play store..When i scroll left side in the body then the sidebar should appear...

Is there any idea to make such a sidebar?

Comment: Have you got any idea on how to make one?

Comment: A link to it, at least?

Comment: no brother! how to?

Answer (score 0):

For js.

```
$(function () {
  var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;
  if (!msie6 && $('#sidebar').offset()!=null) {
    var top = $('#sidebar').offset().top - parseFloat($('#sidebar').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
    var height = $('#sidebar').height();
    var footerTop = $('#footer').offset().top - parseFloat($('#footer').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
    var gap = 15;
    scrollingSideBar(top,height,footerTop,gap);
    $(window).resize(function (event) {
      scrollingSideBar(top,height,footerTop,gap);
    });
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
      scrollingSideBar(top,height,footerTop,gap);
    });
  }
});

function scrollingSideBar(top,height,footerTop,gap){
  var winHeight = $(window).height();
  var winWidth = $(window).width();
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  var x = $(this).scrollLeft();
  if (height+top+gap < winHeight) {
    $('#sidebar').css({ position: "fixed",top: top, left:-x});
  } else if(y+winHeight > height+top+gap){
    $('#sidebar').css({position: "fixed",top: winHeight-height-gap, left:-x});
  } else if (y+winHeight > footerTop) {
    $('#sidebar').css({position: "fixed",top: footerTop-height-y-gap, left:-x});
  } else {
    $('#sidebar').css({position: "absolute",top: top, left:-x/winWidth});
  }
}
```

For CSS you just right click on browser and inspect it.